# Chromedriver is not recognized

Tags: python, cmd, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am trying to install chromedriver to practice web scraping but when I run
`C:\Users\Admin>chromedriver`

I get back
`'chromedriver' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I followed this video but I cannot figure out what I did differently

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVXcVcTRXd0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe chromedriver is not in your PATH.
Try to go to the directory where chromedriver.exe is with the command 'cd', then type chromedriver as you typed. That should work.

Comment: Thank you! It worked I just had to do cd C:\Webdrivers (The folder I added). Now it is up and running.

Comment: great ! If you want, you can add chromedriver.exe in your PATH. (I think you ll find tutorials to do it) and when it s in your path, you can use the command chromedriver where you want.

Comment: I will try that

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the chromedriver to your path to be able to access it and run it from anywhere on your laptop.